# How can I create a column of averages in a dataframe that is sorted by a category in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, average, categories, frequency

I'm making a plot of frequency(x-axis) to size(y-axis).

I currently have a data frame which has a column with categories (as an example category 1, 2, 3 4....), and one with the number of data points for each category - frequency (eg. category 1 has 24 data points).

What I would like to do is add an additional column to this dataframe which includes the average size of the samples (data points) in each category (this information is in another loaded dataframe)

I've tried to do this using this code: `data.frame$averagesize <- mean(data.frameOG$Size)`

However this just gives me the same overall average in each row in the new average size.

Just wondering if there is an argument I can add into my code to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps a 'join, groupby, calculate' approach would work? e.g. `library(tidyverse); full_join(dataframe1, dataframeOG) %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(averagesize = mean(Size))` (it's difficult to say without a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 1):

Do either of these methods solve your problem?

```r
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS[1:10],
                  groups = c("group_1", "group_2"),
                  numbers = sample(1:10, 10))
df1
#>    letters  groups numbers
#> 1        A group_1       3
#> 2        B group_2      10
#> 3        C group_1       2
#> 4        D group_2       8
#> 5        E group_1       6
#> 6        F group_2       9
#> 7        G group_1       1
#> 8        H group_2       7
#> 9        I group_1       5
#> 10       J group_2       4
df2 <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS[1:10],
                  groups = c("group_1", "group_2"),
                  size = round(abs(rnorm(10, 50, 30)), 0))
df2
#>    letters  groups size
#> 1        A group_1   12
#> 2        B group_2   29
#> 3        C group_1   37
#> 4        D group_2   87
#> 5        E group_1   61
#> 6        F group_2   62
#> 7        G group_1   53
#> 8        H group_2   33
#> 9        I group_1  104
#> 10       J group_2   65

means <- aggregate(df2$size, by = list(df2$groups), FUN = mean)
df1 <- merge(x = df1, y = means, by.x = "groups", by.y = "Group.1") 
df1
#>     groups letters numbers    x
#> 1  group_1       A       3 53.4
#> 2  group_1       C       2 53.4
#> 3  group_1       E       6 53.4
#> 4  group_1       G       1 53.4
#> 5  group_1       I       5 53.4
#> 6  group_2       B      10 55.2
#> 7  group_2       D       8 55.2
#> 8  group_2       F       9 55.2
#> 9  group_2       H       7 55.2
#> 10 group_2       J       4 55.2

library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS[1:10],
                  groups = c("group_1", "group_2"),
                  numbers = sample(1:10, 10))
df1
#>    letters  groups numbers
#> 1        A group_1       3
#> 2        B group_2      10
#> 3        C group_1       2
#> 4        D group_2       8
#> 5        E group_1       6
#> 6        F group_2       9
#> 7        G group_1       1
#> 8        H group_2       7
#> 9        I group_1       5
#> 10       J group_2       4
df2 <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS[1:10],
                  groups = c("group_1", "group_2"),
                  size = round(abs(rnorm(10, 50, 30)), 0))
df2
#>    letters  groups size
#> 1        A group_1   12
#> 2        B group_2   29
#> 3        C group_1   37
#> 4        D group_2   87
#> 5        E group_1   61
#> 6        F group_2   62
#> 7        G group_1   53
#> 8        H group_2   33
#> 9        I group_1  104
#> 10       J group_2   65

df1 %>%
  full_join(df2) %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate(averagesize_df2 = mean(size))
#> Joining, by = c("letters", "groups")
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#> # Groups:   groups [2]
#>    letters groups  numbers  size averagesize_df2
#>    <chr>   <chr>     <int> <dbl>           <dbl>
#>  1 A       group_1       3    12            53.4
#>  2 B       group_2      10    29            55.2
#>  3 C       group_1       2    37            53.4
#>  4 D       group_2       8    87            55.2
#>  5 E       group_1       6    61            53.4
#>  6 F       group_2       9    62            55.2
#>  7 G       group_1       1    53            53.4
#>  8 H       group_2       7    33            55.2
#>  9 I       group_1       5   104            53.4
#> 10 J       group_2       4    65            55.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>